# Store either a singleton OR a mock implementing the same interface

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a class which accepts an interface:

```cpp
class interface {
   public:
    virtual ~interface() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class user {
    interface& impl_;

   public:
    user(interface& impl) : impl_(impl) {}

    void foo_user() { impl_.foo(); }
};
```

One of the implementations of this interface is required to be a singleton for third-party reasons. I also have a simulated implementation, which has no need to be a singleton:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>

class singleton_impl : public interface {
    singleton_impl() = default;

   public:
    static singleton_impl& instance() {
        static singleton_impl i;
        return i;
    }

    void foo() override { std::printf("foo\n"); };
};

class mock_impl : public interface {
    void foo() override { std::printf("mock foo\n"); };
};
```

Whoever uses `user` needs to provide one of those, based on some runtime criteria:

```cpp
#include <cstring>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    bool is_sim = argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "--sim") == 0;

    interface* impl = nullptr;

    if (is_sim)
        impl = new mock_impl;
    else
        impl = &singleton_impl::instance();

    user u{*impl};

    u.foo_user();

    if (is_sim) delete impl;

    return 0;
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgAMwA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/kEZWY4CYRHRLHEJKbaY9qUMQgRMxAR5Pn6BdQ05za0E5VGx8UmpCi1tHQXdEwNDldVjAJS2qF7EyOwc5onhyN5YANQmiW7IE/iop9gmGgCCu/uHmCdnFwTE4cA3d48PByYCgUR3CBHiVCYWxOySsDyOCLSXhitDwyBAfwRCIAbng2l4xEcAH5giFQzAQZZvAAiRywkK8tAIpzh9yxR1x%2BMJ2NQeHQR34qEpNKOGhZfxMyWp4oef0BwKOXiUxBhrPZpOIkK25gCoJYaVoAH0Zf82Yjkaj0ZisUr4hANVrMDq9QaqSAXUb7fraFTJVYpRL4VieXyBahUIbbcRhX6PYaAHSCyksmHS2UBxKsuUGBVZIz0IgMQ14b1Hd1IlFo0GCMnQv3WhF54AFgTF70xxK0%2BlMRnMzOBs1HCuWjFBxstRzII5NltFksG53hOYMLYx2EN9nTidVmeYQttg2gk2brHEPcbBhH/tj1MD9kh/lJqmobHxL7HWOXEAgNJfQRUCBzDMQUTAAVjcBggOWFNJWla9HgzLMARzEEWFQZAAGsD1oMshwtKsHXJVUNwfMMhWfV9iHfV5PwIdBv1/MEAKAtDMLIsCIKgmDEIlHjZQeMEjhYJhwntQQjlaYBkFII5kAQVoACoFIk4hgGxX11xvAB6LSjhicMcLwBRDSyFgRUkqcbiOLgTkCZ0Jk2fUIEk7EwIsLgwOpGSgIAWh80yoJpU5aTFeD2R0vSDNBYzTJFSFaCUY8sX0zxopMksRU%2BLwnXgjdCK2ZT5xw4KjgYRlaDST4TTyqgjntGKS2gm91VLEqIgAdyE9CsKKpKEXqRLmqxIqRR1Xd9yK78lxaFcKWg3KbyjRU/QU3q%2BNNdkvETcNI2VZMFsHUFavq9KWCpLAC1eXqDvZM8CAvUVqqlDhVloThQN4PwOC0UhUE4NxrGsad1k2GizESHhSAITQXtWDCQFAjR4wADnB0CzAATkkLguGSAJJFSN6OEkT6Yd%2BzheAUEANChmHVjgWAYEQFBUH1Oh4nISg0DZ%2BgEkBIwuACDQaawXEtgANTwTB2oAeTSRhOEhmgmXiKmIBiMmYnCVoAE9Fd4LXmGIHWZZibRMAcfXSG5thBBlhhaD177eCwYT822H78DPBw8FfKnneCVQLa8cEydJImftRGJiF1jwsDJz4S311YqAMYAFEl6W5YV7heH4QQRDEdgpBkQRFBUdQA90Lh9EMYxAcsfQ8BiKnYGYNgQHT2hSEozhEg0HhllWVBKpyf3KfqC3GhcBh3E8To9FCcJhiqUYa%2BKbIBGmPx18yTeGAWEYEhruwp76SZ2nngoT8nn2BH6NpD9X4/bAv7e9DmR/l8WNfVgUEGtgSFeu9UmAc/ocCOKoZGAQfL41kgYIw1kAjxiRhoOquBCAkFshDZYvBobOyHqQeGKR4ygX0JwEmpAWAgACBjeMkhJDIyxgEUCXBQKJAxskDQyNSBfR%2BuAym1NaYENIAzZm6wCBIgIJzCAmB8BEHfHofOwhRDiBLso8uagybV1IO1GOaRk7kI4B9XhZNwEyxDlIo4qBapQJgXA/mwAkEoJQXVDwPN4jYK4Lg4RWhCEIEwEwLACRKRGModQ/upDWEaHYYwyQQtMa41MWAimtghH4L8XDEAkg6G43xlw0CyNUaJHYUYxIoD%2BGpIybDIxZgKm8AEb4mplEsjOEkEAA%3D%3D)

What's the simplest way to avoid the raw pointer/delete here, while avoiding turning `mock_impl` into a singleton itself (my current solution)? I want some kind of smart pointer that either owns or doesn't own its underlying object.

I could also *always* construct the mock object and then just conditionally pass it to the `user`, but I feel that I shouldn't need to keep a random object around.

Comment: This article seems to offer a few solutions, none of which are particularly appealing but could be improved with templates: https://japreiss.wordpress.com/2013/07/21/dependency-injection-in-c/